# CARACTER INESPERADO "\" (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo el siguiente código para guardar unos datos, genero la direccion de acuerdo al código mostrado. el problema, el `pathguarda` cumple su parte, con las diagonales correctas "\".

Al concatenar con el resto de datos para la creación de la dirección, al agregar el diagonal invertido, NO LO RECONOCE, indica que es un carácter inesperado.Como lo podría solucionar? 
este carácter necesito que lo reconozca, para que al llamarlo en la condición, pueda ir a la dirección deseada.

```
 string pathguarda = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xFacturas"].ToString()
                                string pathguarda_en = pathguarda +"\" + _year +"\"+ _mes +"\"+ _dia +"\";
                                if (!Directory.Exists(@pathguarda_en))
                                {
                                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathguarda_en);
                                }
                                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes indicar el Path con doble barra invertida `\\`. Prueba de esta manera:

```
string pathguarda_en = pathguarda +"\\" + _year +"\\"+ _mes +"\\"+ _dia +"\\";
```

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con una doble diagonal, pues es un [caracter de escape](https://riptutorial.com/es/csharp/topic/39/secuencias-de-escape-de-cadena).

```
string pathguarda = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xFacturas"].ToString()
                            string pathguarda_en = pathguarda +"\\" + _year +"\\"+ _mes +"\\"+ _dia +"\\";
                            if (!Directory.Exists(@pathguarda_en))
                            {
                                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathguarda_en);
                            }
                            }
```